# Designing efficient C++ code for fibers

Tags: c++, io, fibers

How do I utilize fibers best in my game code? Should it only be used to manage nonpreemptive context-switches while loading resources (i.e. files from disk)? Or do I allow all types of game entities to run in a fiber? How do I schedule?

C++ or pseudo code samples greatly appreciated!

Comment: would you mind posting a link to exactly what you are referring to (fibers)? I have never heard of this term before, and am curious as to what you are talking about.

Comment: Tried to post Wikipedia link, but Stackoverflow couldn't handle it. Search for Fiber (computer science) in Wikipedia.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't? It's like a thread only with very little CRT support (unlike threads) and some hidden memory requirements like stack and registers.

It may make non-system code easier to write but it complicates to an unjustifiable degree.

Comment: Fibers are notoriously subtle, and I've never heard of a major piece of production software that used them extensively and successfully (though I've heard of plenty that tried, then quit.)

Comment: You never heard of Stackless Python (http://stackless.com) or Eve Online (http://eveonline.com)?